Index перенаправляет на localhost, но с другими роутами все нормально
Пытаюсь настроить переадресацию с порта 80 на порт 3030 через nginx.
Все работает, если я ввожу например http://123.321.123.321/news (123.321.123.321 - вымышленный ip), то все работает, но если я введу просто http://123.321.123.321, то меня попытается перекинуть на localhost:3030 (на моем компе, где не стоит сервер)
вот файл nginx.conf
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 123.321.123.321;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

У меня запущен сайт на фреймворке Flask, через nginx я настраиваю просто переадресацию на порт 80. И index.html на моем сайте есть
